# Trello - Adding the same attachment to multiple cards

Tags: trello

I am currently using Trello to manage a short film project.  I have uploaded sketches for each shot of my film but have several boards that require use of the same image.
I wondered if there was a way for me to reference the same images across multiple boards and cards.

At the minute I am uploading the same image several times.  Or I have been adding a direct link to the current uploaded file.  This appears as a hyperlink in the comments but doesn't give me the preview in the Trello card window which is what I want.

Even though there is currently no cap on space per user I am still conscious of uploading several files that are identical as it just seems to be a waste of space.

Am I missing something or is this a feature that does not yet exist?

Answer (score 1):

For the foreseeable future, just upload the image. Or you could use an image sharing site like http://imgur.com and just put in the URL.

I think the best way for Trello to solve this would be to pull down the image from a URL. For instance, when you paste a link from any of the popular image sharing sites to the chat client HipChat, it pulls down a preview of the image so you don't have to visit it. You could put in the URL multiple times and get a copy of the image each time without creating multiple uploads.

Comment: That sounds like it would be great!  For now I will just continue as I have been.  :)  Thanks for your answer.